# Проблема с кодировкой при рисовании картинок на php

Tags: php

Рисую картинку на php, но не могу решить проблему с кодировкой для рус.символов.
Пытался вот так:
1) в заголовке хедер (смешно, для картинки, но пытался - не помогло).

```
header ("Content-type: image/png; charset='utf-8'");
```

2) для запроса с базы данных:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf-8');
```

3) и функцией iconv:

```
$rust = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', 'мой красивый код');
```

или

```
$rust = iconv('cp1251', 'UTF-8', 'мой красивый код');
```

или

```
$rust = iconv('cp1250', 'UTF-8', 'мой красивый код');
```

По отдельности включал, все вместе, и частями добавлял - проблема не решилась :(
Подскажите, куда копать...
спасибо.

Comment: `не могу решить проблему с кодировкой для рус.символов` - какую именно проблему вы пытались решить? В чем эта проблема заключается вы забыли описать... ну и стоит написать весь код, который вы пишите

Comment: В бд самой какая кодировка?

Comment: покажите код....

Comment: всем спасибо,:) воспользовался функцией imagettftext, и добавил свои шрифты. :)